# Postgresql selecting first item of last group

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have this data:

```
ID | Amount
1 | 0
2 | 0
3 | 0
4 | 0 ---> NULL

ID | Amount
1 | -1 ---> this row
2 | 0
3 | 0
4 | 0
5 | 0

ID | Amount
1 | 0
2 | 0
3 | -1 ---> this row
4 | 0
5 | 0
6 | 0
7 | 0

ID | Amount
1 | 0
2 | -1
3 | -1
4 | 0
5 | 0
6 | -1 ---> this row
7 | 0
8 | 0

ID | Amount
1 | 0
2 | -1
3 | 0
4 | 0
5 | 0
6 | -1 ---> this row
7 | -1
8 | 0
```

my logic is start at the end, and move up until we hit the first -1. However, I am unable to arrive at an SQL for this. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is there any column can represent order number?

Comment: Table data is unordered unless you explicitly order them (by one or more columns). How did you order your data to define where is `the end` and `move up`? And what is your expected output? As you describe, it seem only output one row with -1 value if found, or no row if not found -1 in your table?

Comment: @D-Shih we can assume there is a row number column that. I'll add it in sample data

Comment: @PhamX.Bach I have put the sample data in order. Adding the order column in sample for clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have `-1`s, you can group them by counting the `0`s that follow.  These can then be enumerated using `dense_rank()`:

```
select id, rnk
from (select t.*, dense_rank() over (partition by grp) as rnk
      from (select t.*,
                   count(*) filter (where amount = 0) over (order by id desc) as grp
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where amount = -1 and rnk = 1
order by id
fetch first 1 row only;
```

To handle your first case, you can union in a query like this:

```
select id, rnk
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t where amount = -1)
order by id
fetch first 1 row only
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even know half of these functions! This really helps!